# Android ScrollView not srcoll inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have RelativeLayout inside SrcollView. That ScrollView will be an child of LinearLayout. In RelativeLayout I added views programmatically. But ScrollView is not scrolling.
startActivityCenterLayout - place between AutocompleteTextView's container and Button's container.
How I can resolve it?

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/startActivityRootLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/dark_cyan"
    tools:context="com.geodevteam.geopay.project.activity.StartActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/startActivityTopLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/dark_cyan">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityLogoImageView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ico"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityLogoTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            style="@style/ApplicationNameTextView"
            android:text="@string/application_title"/>

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityAutocompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            style="@style/AutocompleteTextViewTextColor"
            android:hint="@string/start_to_input_name"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startActivityCenterLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/startActivityTopLayout"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_cyan">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityCenterLayoutScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardsRootLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/startActivityBottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/dark_cyan">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startActivitySocialsButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_by_mail_button"
            style="@style/LoginByMailButton"
            android:text="@string/login_sign_using_social" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startActivityEmailButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_by_mail_button"
            style="@style/LoginByMailButton"
            android:text="@string/login_using_mail" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Since you've nothing besides the scrollView inside the linearlayout set ScrollView as the root element.

Comment: Scrollview only scroll when child layout has more child that can not be shown in screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now scrollview is working. Code down below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/startActivityRootLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/dark_cyan"
    tools:context="com.geodevteam.geopay.project.activity.StartActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/startActivityTopLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/dark_cyan">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityLogoImageView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ico"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityLogoTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            style="@style/ApplicationNameTextView"
            android:text="@string/application_title"/>

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityAutocompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            style="@style/AutocompleteTextViewTextColor"
            android:hint="@string/start_to_input_name"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/startActivityBottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/dark_cyan">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startActivitySocialsButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_by_mail_button"
            style="@style/LoginByMailButton"
            android:text="@string/login_sign_using_social" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startActivityEmailButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_by_mail_button"
            style="@style/LoginByMailButton"
            android:text="@string/login_using_mail" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/startActivityCenterLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/startActivityBottomLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/startActivityTopLayout"
        android:background="@color/dark_cyan">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/startActivityCenterLayoutScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardsRootLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout is scrollable if necessary, so if you didn't put anything inside the Relative Layout, you aren't able to scroll.

Comment: I put CarView inside RelativeLayout programmatically

Comment: And you can't see all of that view?

Comment: I can't. I was edited question and attached a picture.

Comment: the code you just posted doesnt match the picture that you posted

Comment: @Nenco 'cause it is only center container. I add this in question description

Answer (score 0):

This is Because hight of your `ScrollView` is `0dp`. And Regarding that `weight` you have given to `ScrollView`is work only if you have given `weightSum` to parent `LinearLayout`.

Eighter you give `weightSum` to `LinrearLayout` or Change Hight of `ScrollView` to `match_parent`.

Happy Coding.

Comment: set ScrollView's height to match_parent. Still don't working

Comment: can you post your whole xml?